# Android - SMS Popup, wont open over itself

Tags: android, android-activity

I have made an app that opens a popup, everything is working fine getting the SMS content, sender name and picture.
When a SMS is received it opens a popup shows all the details. But if the popup is already open it wont open another popup showing the content of the second SMS.
The thing that bothers me alot is that, I have `PreferenceActivity` for this app. When this activity is open then the app is able to open multiple popups, else it doesnt.
I would like to ask
1. How can I make my app to open multiple popups?
2. Why is it when `PreferenceActivity` is open, the app can make multiple popups

Some details:
For case 1, log is **NOT** giving me any sort of warning or error.
I have tried to use  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` and `android:launchMode= "standard"`
I have this AlertDialog in an activity, starting this activity from a `broadcastreveiver`

Thank you.

Comment: How does your app create the 'popup' window?

Comment: I am using a alertdialog with custom title and view..

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed one popup window at a time and in this case you can treat Dialog like a Popup Window. I'm skeptical that you are able to see more than one popup window in your Preference Activity, but you may be seeing something that looks like it but isn't really more than one. This can be easily checked by using the hierarchy viewer to see what is actually layered.

If you want to have something like layered messages, like in a carousel, card edges, or use some other visual indication you would have use/build a custom view.